# jQGrid Number to text while Export to Excel

Tags: jquery, html, excel, jqgrid, export-to-excel

I am using jqgrid 5.3.2

This is My Function which get the data server

```
function GetReportData(gridData) {
            var grid_selector = "#DeliveryStatusReportGrid";
            var pager_selector = "#DeliveyStatusReportpager_list_1";

            $(grid_selector).jqGrid({
                data: gridData,
                datatype: "local",
                height: 400,
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                rowNum: 13,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                colNames: ['Code', 'CardAccountNo'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'Code', width: 10, key: true, align: 'center', hidden: true },

                { name: 'Card_Number', width: 1000, index: 'Card_Number', width: 20, search: true, align: 'center' },
                ],
                pager: pager_selector,
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: "Customer Gift Report",
                hidegrid: false,
                loadComplete: function () {
                    $(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridWidth', $(grid_selector).closest(".jqgrid").width());
                    jQuery(grid_selector).trigger('resize');
                }
            }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);
        }
```

This is my export to excel

```
$("#exportToExcel").on("click", function () {
            $("#DeliveryStatusReportGrid").jqGrid("exportToExcel", {
                includeLabels: true,
                includeGroupHeader: true,
                includeFooter: true,
                fileName: "DeliveryStatus.xlsx",
                maxlength: 40 // maxlength for visible string data
            })
        })
```

But when i export to excel My number changes
**For ex - 5402760000484016 to  5402760000484010**
Excel Number Formatting Issue
So i want to convert my number to text so that it does not change or formats while Export to Excel using Jqgrid
Any Help is Thankful

Comment: So you want the actual value or you want the converted value?

Comment: I want my actual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a problem in excel, which can't handle a numbers over 15 digits. You can read more on this [problem here](http://excelunplugged.com/2014/05/19/15-digit-limit-in-excel/)

We have take care about this problem and have fixed it setting the number to be displayed as string when they are > 15 digits. If you are a licensed user, please let us know and we will send you the fix.

The problem can be solved with the current release using the custom formatter, where when the values is exported to excel to add to it a space at end of the value.

```
{ name: 'Card_Number', 
    width: 1000, 
    index: 'Card_Number', 
    width: 20, 
    search: true, 
    align: 'center',
    formatter : function ( value, options, rdata) {
        if( options.exporttype === "excel") {
            return value+' ';
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
 }
```